# Does $\chi_{p(\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} f_n)}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\chi_{p(f_n)}$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Is $\chi_{p(\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n)}=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\chi_{p(f_n)}$, assuming $\lim f_n$ exists? Here $\chi_{p(f)}$ is $1$ for the set where the proposition $p$ on the function $f$ is true and $0$ for otherwise. Here the functions are $[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ and the limits are almost everywhere convergence.

Comment: What sort of functions, and what sort of convergence?

Comment: @Scott, I edited the question addressing your comment.

Comment: One last question: is that a.e. convergence with respect to Lebesgue measure?

Comment: @Scott, yes it is.

Comment: @Edgar: Please avoid using `\displaystyle` in the title.

Comment: @AsafKaragila why?

Comment: @AsafKaragila got it,sorry

Comment: @AsafKaragila I can not edit more questions, it is forever?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Try $p=$ "being bounded" and $f_n(x)=\min\{n,1/x\}$.

Comment: $\lim\chi_{f_n}=1$ and $\chi_{\lim f_n}=1$ a.e. So, I think your example is not a counter example.

Comment: See revised version.

Answer (score 0):

Or: $p(f)$ means "the function $f$ is identically zero", and $f_n(x) = 1/n$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and all $n \in \mathbb N$.